# Getting error while login

Tags: integration, login-errors, website-integration, grant-login-access

i am able to login to my dev without any issues.
but it’s not working from our development server(drupal).
getting the below error

> Array ( [faultcode] => sf:LOGIN_DURING_RESTRICTED_DOMAIN [faultstring]
>   => LOGIN_DURING_RESTRICTED_DOMAIN: cannot log in from current domain [detail] => Array ( [LoginFault] => Array ( [exceptionCode] =>
>   LOGIN_DURING_RESTRICTED_DOMAIN [exceptionMessage] => cannot log in
>   from current domain ) ) )

i think this is due to IP restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means IP restriction has been added to the users profile, and the login request is not from the set of allowed IP addresses.

Please add the IP in Setup > Manage Users > Profiles >  Login IP Ranges.

Let me know if this helps.